# how to fix update problem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, 16.04

While update I have got error like this

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

Comment: thanks mate for your response . But I have already saw this issue , and I couldn't solve it

Comment: Open **Software & Updates** application and go to **Other Software** tab and uncheck the sources that are added multiple times. After that close and reload cache to update software sources.

Answer (score 35):

This happened to me in a recent install, too, but I had installed the Google repository - I see that you have installed it, as well, in your first line...

Navigated to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Edited google.list by invoking `sudo nano google.list`.

Commented out the source with a `#`

Saved and ran `sudo apt-get update`

**In case you like to do it in the terminal:**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

```
#deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Save and Close the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and try updating using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error solved!

Comment: Renaming the file/echoing to google-chrome.list worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same kind of problem. I go in `/etc/sources.list` then I open the files concerned by the error.

I saw that a line was repeated and I just removed one of the duplicated lines.

Now I don't have the error anymore.