# Update Problem - Cannot Ping

Tags: gnome, updates

Stats: 17.04, originally Unity, now Gnome.

Software Updater fails to update.  Changing settings and then reloading allows more detail in the UI and the ubuntu archive zesty-security and zesty-updates both seem to load a little then stop, stating:

> Failed to download repository information

But then says 'the software on this computer is up to date'.

Terminal update gives.... well apparently I can't post address.  Oh Dear.  Okay - I'll edit the terminal output.

> Hit:6 [address] InRelease
>   Get:7 [address] xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
>   Err:11 rs.archive.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease
>     Could not connect to rs.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (147.91.175.253), connection timed out
>   Fetched 370 kB in 2min 0s (3078 B/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   W: Failed to fetch 
>   W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

That little 'rs' means Serbia.  Changed Software Updater to download from the UK - failure.

I can ping the ubuntu archive but not when it has the 'rs' prefix (I wish I could just post the addresses but this is my first post).

The system has no firewall.  My girlfriend seems to be having the same issue on her Ubuntu 16 LTS machine.  Her updater runs into problems downloading some Tor package, but it's the same IP: 147.91.175.253 which cannot be reached (or pinged).

Changed WiFi and restarted.  Nada.

Changed Software Updator to download from the UK's mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk/ubuntu.  No success.

Funny thing is that I can brows to this InRelease file.  I don't know how to add it manually so I saved it as a file, named it InRelease.deb then ran dpkg -i.  Apparently this is not how it works.

Any thoughts much appreciated.  I know nothing but I can follow instructions and do basic research.

PS: Just so you know that this is urgent, my girlfriend cannot install cowsay.

Answer (score 0):

Well I seemed to have solved it.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766354/how-to-fix-update-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04) was not the solution, but it suggested I look under /etc/apt/ then use

> sudo nano sources.list

At this point I noticed that some items had the prefix 'rs.ubuntu' while others were at 'gb.ubuntu'.  I changed all 'rs' prefixes to 'gb'.

It worked, and the Software Updater works fine too now.  Looks like it was just some problem with Serbia.